# How to save .txt file to E3 (AWS) with Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have no troubles reading a .txt file from S3 with the following line

```
 lines = sc.textFile("s3n://gvdata/ETL_Data/example.txt")
```

but when I want to open a file, write something into it and save it to my bucket in S3

```
filename = "s3n://gvdata/myLog-%s.txt"%datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%y')
f = open(filename,'w')
f.write("blabla %s \n" %datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%y_%H:%M:%S'))
f.close()
```

I get `"No such file or directory"`.

Anyone knows how to change it?

Thanks in advance!